# Google Maps "cropping"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Okay so this may sound like a crazy question, but I have a Google Map (API v3) on a website, and at times I have a large number of markers on the map.  Are there any plugins that exist, or how difficult would it be to write one, (starter code?) that would allow me to let the user say hit contrl + left mouse click and hold and enable them to "select" a portion of the map.  After which when they release the left mouse button, I could fire an off a function that could update my google map to reset the zoom and only include the markers within the users selection area.

I'm really really wanting to try this, does anyone have any pointers or ideas that could help me?

**UPDATE**

Okay, is it even possible? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is possible however I think there is a better way to solve your problem which is to use [clustering](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html).

For the cropping you could:

1. Use event addDomListener to listen for 'mousedown' on the map. Check the event object passed to the handler to see if the ctrl key is pressed (e.ctrlKey).
2. Convert the x y coordinates for the mouse click into a lat lng (use fromPointToLatLng on the map projection). Create a rectangle at the position.
3. Add a addDomListener mousemove handler on the map. In the handler resize the rectangle using setBounds.
4. Add a addDomListener mouseup handler on the map. In the handler grab the bounds of the rectangle, remove the rectangle and call map.fitBounds.

I haven't tried the above but after all that typing I would recommend trying out clustering first to see if it satisfies your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  The clustering option won't work for me because the purpose of reducing the markers to only those in the viewport is to allow me to make a static map image, and if too many markers are present the URL limit is exceeded.  What I ended up doing is using the 'dragend' and 'zoom_changed' events of the map, and on each fire a function that gets ONLY the markers in the viewable area.  That way I can still convert the map to an image, just requires the user zoom in to an area that doesn't exceed the limit.