# How to crop part of <p:gmap>?

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces, crop

I have a `<p:gmap>` with specific markers. I would like to crop a part of that `<p:gmap>`. I can't do it with `<p:imageCropper>`, because it crops an image, not a Google Map. How can I capture a specific part of the Google Map?

This is my map bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class InfoWindowView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    GestionAnalyseLocal m;

    private MapModel advancedModel;

    private Marker marker;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        advancedModel = new DefaultMapModel();

        List<Analyse> alys = new ArrayList<Analyse>();
        alys = m.findAll();
        for (int i = 2; i <= alys.size(); i++) {
            Double x = null;
            Double y = null;
            try {
                x = Double.parseDouble(alys.get(i).getLongitude());
                y = Double.parseDouble(alys.get(i).getLatitude());

                LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(y, x);
                if (alys.get(i).getUu_HandoffOk() == 1) {
                    advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "test", "point.png",
                            "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_blue.png  "));
                } else {
                    if (alys.get(i).getUu_OutgoingCallOk() == 1) {
                        advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "test", "phone",
                                "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon52.png"));
                    }
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("err");
            }

        }

    }

    public MapModel getAdvancedModel() {
        return advancedModel;
    }

    public void onMarkerSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event) {
        marker = (Marker) event.getOverlay();
    }

    public Marker getMarker() {
        return marker;
    }
}
```

And this is the JSF page:

```
  <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true|false" type="text/javascript" ></script>

 </h:head>
<h:body>
 <h:form >
 <h:commandButton action="#{infoWindowView.init()}" value="Generate" />

 </h:form>
 <h:form>
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="left,right" style="width:100%">
        <p:chart type="pie" model="#{chartView.pieModel1}" style="width:400px;height:300px">
            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{chartView.itemSelect}" update="growl" />
        </p:chart>



    </h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
<h:form>  
    <p:gmap id="gmap" center="36.8189700,10.1657900" zoom="12" type="HYBRID" model="#{infoWindowView.advancedModel}" style="width:100%;height:400px">

        <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{infoWindowView.onMarkerSelect}" />

        <p:gmapInfoWindow id="infoWindow">
            <p:outputPanel style="text-align: center; display: block; margin: auto">

                        <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/orange.png" height="150" />
                    <br />
                    <h:outputText value="#{infoWindowView.marker.title}" />

            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:gmapInfoWindow>
    </p:gmap>

    <!-- Preload for demo -->
    <p:outputPanel style="display:none">

        <p:graphicImage name="images/#{orange.png}" title="orange.png" />
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
</h:body>
  </ui:composition>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this personally but I've read about using **Clustering** to simplify your data visualization or to capture a specific part of the Google Map by consolidating data that are nearby each other on the map in an aggregate form. Existing methods to be used can be found in [MarkerClusterer for Google Maps](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) and for varied approaches, [Too Many Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#introduction) might put additional input that can satisfy your desired output.

Comment: SO post - [Google Maps “cropping”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212547/google-maps-cropping) might also help.

Comment: Thank you for your response i will see it ^^

Answer (score 0):

By cropping map you mean you still want all the map facilities but for the selected region then you can do something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=65.738268&lng=244.306000&zoom=3&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/so_wholeworldkmld.kml)(take another map when user tries to crop the map and get the coordinates from original map build set the selected region to new map and show to the user) user still will be able to use the map facilities.

Comment: Thank you for your  response, but this cant help me cuz i should crop what the user see and wanna crop ( he can zoom or select some markers ...) i found a [solution](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) i will try it and if this dont work i will use phantomJS to capture the interface and resize it  ^^

Comment: All the best if it is done don't forget to put answer here so that it will help somebody... :)